# How to get USA Transit Visa From India and What is the current waiting time

Tags: visas, usa, transit-visas

I will be travelling Mexico in the near future. When I searched for the flights i could see most of the flights are going via USA land. So How to apply for USA Transit from India now. And what is the current waiting time to get the USA Transit visa in this case

Comment: Note that the US consulate in Hyderabad is reporting a 23-day wait for visas other than visitor visas and student/exchange visas.

Comment: where you are seeing this  am seeing in https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/other-visa-categories/transit.html and it is showing that 219 days for other types.

Comment: I also see 219 days.  Perhaps there was some error in the system earlier, or perhaps they had just opened a bunch of new appointments that have since been filled, or something like that.  Chennai now has 29 days for student visas.  I don't remember for sure, but I think that was in the hundreds a couple of days ago.  If I were you I'd keep my eye on these numbers in the hope of catching some newly added appointments (or perhaps newly available because of cancellation) at some point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the details are stated on [this page from the US Departement of State](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/other-visa-categories/transit.html).

The procedure involves applying online then going through an interview.

The same page also has a form at the bottom which allows you to find out waiting times. I looked up Mumbai and New Delhi and both had waiting times of over a year.

You will probably need to find some other routing. Note that if you opt to connect through and airport in the Schengen Area instead, you may need an Airport Transit Visa from the relevant country (this depends on the country where you transit).

Comment: A traveler using an Indian regular passport (that is, not an official passport nor a diplomatic passport) needs an airport transit visa only in the Czech Republic, France, Germany, or Spain.  This list may change from time to time (France has been on it only since April 2021).  The current list is linked as a PDF file from this page: https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/policies/schengen-borders-and-visa/visa-policy_en  Hyderabad has a 23-day wait, however.